# Jetty+Jersey, unexpected exception: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm developing a JAX-RS server where I need to provide answers to client asynchronously. I'm loading the Server programmatically. To my purposes, I'm using Jetty and the Jersey implementation. Here you have my relevant parts of code:

// file: EntryPoint.java

```
@Path("/explorer")
public class EntryPoint {

@GET
@Path("/{table}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void querySearch( @PathParam     ("table")   String          table, 
                         @QueryParam    ("source")  String          source, 
                         @QueryParam    ("from")    int             startTime, 
                         @QueryParam    ("until")   int             endTime,
                         @Suspended     final       AsyncResponse   asyncResponse) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
            asyncResponse.resume(result);
        }

        private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
            return "{\"Source\":"+source+",\"Table\":\""+table+",\"StartTime\":\""+startTime+",\"EndTime\":\""+endTime+"\"}";
        }
    }).start();
}
```

// file: Service.java

```
private void startWS(String address, int port) throws Exception, InterruptedException {

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    Server jettyServer = new Server();

    // HTTP connector
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(jettyServer);
    http.setHost(address);
    http.setPort(port);

    jettyServer.addConnector(http);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
       "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
       EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }
}
```

// pom.xml (only relevant dependencies... I put the version in each dep)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The server runs and goes up correctly, however, when I try to invoke my service I get the following exception:

```
12:39:22:497|3698-00048:WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel] - //pisa122:9090/explorer/cm_order?ource=BBG_BOND&from=20160410&until=20160418 Thread {qtp872786524-48}
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$3.suspend(WebComponent.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.suspend(ResponseWriter.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.suspend(ServerRuntime.java:910)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:327)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
... 24 more
```

The very same request, when I return synchronously, works with no problems. I also checked in the maven Dependency Hierarchy and I do see the 3.1 version of the servlet-api (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMBk3.png)). Any idea of what's wrong in my code/pom? I already checked the [Register ServletContainer programatically in Osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802671/register-servletcontainer-programatically-in-osgi) but that didn't help. Thanks all! :)

Comment: what is your web.xml?

Comment: My application is not deployed in a webserver, the server is run programmatically from the application itself

Answer (score 16):

You need the following for servlet 3.x support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. Now I'm wondering which dependency was importing a wrong version of the servlet API or, alternatively, I can only assume the logged error message is misleading... in any case, thanks again :)

Comment: It's not that you were bringing in an older version, it's just that the above dependency is require for 3.x support. The lack of it just assumes you are running an older container, even if you are not. I guess the error may be a little misleading